# Microsoft SQL Server equivalent of MySQL REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I am trying to reconstruct a database query I created for MySQL in Microsoft SQL Server. I am looking for an operator or function SQL Server which acts like `REGEXP`.

Here is an example of how I am using the operator:

```
select *
from   musicdetails
WHERE  artistname REGEXP '^".mysql_escape_string($_GET['search'])."$'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go (compile as SQL CLR assembly):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
  [SqlFunction]
  public static bool RegexMatch(string expr, string regex)
  {
    return Regex.IsMatch(expr, regex);
  }

  [SqlFunction]
  public static string RegexReplace(string expr, string regex, string replace)
  {
    return Regex.Replace(expr, regex, replace);
  }

  [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName="GetToken", 
       TableDefinition="Value nvarchar(max)")]
  public static IEnumerable RegexSplit(string expr, string regex)
  {
    return Regex.Split(expr, regex);
  }

  public static void GetToken(object row, out string str)
  {
     str = (string) row;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do this in SQL Server (2005 and up only) is to use CLR functions; regular expressions as part of native SQL queries isn't standard.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While the code in leppie's answer will compile and execute, I would not recommend it for production use. If you want RegEx functions that:

- are coded using best practices (for performance and security)
- handle `NULL`s appropriately
- perform better / more efficient
- have more options (e.g. `@StartAt`, `@RegExOptions` for **IgnoreCase**, **MultiLine**, etc)
- provide more functionality (e.g. **CaptureGroup**, **CaptureGroupCapture**, **Escape**, **Unescape**, etc)
- require no additional effort to deploy (i.e. a single, self-contained T-SQL script that is portable and versionable, and installs cleanly with no need to manually enable "CLR enabled" or mess with the ["CLR strict security" setting that was introduced in SQL Server 2017](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/07/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-1-clr-strict-security/))

and are also free, then check out the [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_4764373) SQLCLR library (that I wrote). There are 13 RegEx functions in the Free version (and 2 more in the Full / paid version, plus the ability to increase the expression cache size, which can help if you frequently use a variety of expressions).

I believe the function **RegEx_IsMatch** (or **RegEx_IsMatch4k**) is what you are looking for (yes, it is in the Free version).