# how to find this pattern in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

How to find pattern like this in sql server in a table.

I've table with rows like this.

```
ST CLAIR, TERESA
JR VISH, DALVI
JACK RIDER
JR JK, SMITH
```

I want to find the rows which follows this pattern `ST CLAIR, TERESA` so it will return 3 rows like below.

```
ST CLAIR, TERESA
JR VISH, DALVI
JR JK, SMITH
```

Query

```
select * from table
where column like ?
```

Comment: What pattern...? Please describe it more. Two words, comma, another word?

Comment: possible duplicate of [microsoft sql equivalent of mysql REGEXP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515259/microsoft-sql-equivalent-of-mysql-regexp)

Comment: @chx Both are different questions.

Comment: Hard to say without clarification on what you want. `% %, %` will match `100 200, 300`. To match *words* you need regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for a pattern that includes a space character: [column] LIKE '% %, %'

Or if the comma is all you care about just use LIKE '%,%'

Comment: LIKE '% %, %' will work - % % to grab the space and , % for comma and suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
select * from table where column like '% %, %'
```

You can test it like this:

```
WITH Foo (datacol)
AS( SELECT *
    FROM (  VALUES  ('ST CLAIR, TERESA'),
                    ('JR VISH, DALVI'),
                    ('JACK RIDER'), 
                    ('JR JK, SMITH') 
                    ) AS F (datacol))
SELECT datacol
FROM Foo where datacol like '% %, %';
```

It will give you the result you are looking for:

```
 ST CLAIR, TERESA
 JR VISH, DALVI
 JR JK, SMITH
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Luxspes you can use '% %, %' to filter the data or you can use parsename to get the result

```
Declare @Sample table
(word varchar(255))

Insert into @Sample
values 
('ST CLAIR , TERESA'),('JR VISH, DALVI'),('JACK RIDER'),('JR JK, SMITH')

Select word from @Sample
where parsename(replace(word,',','.'),2) is not null
```