# REGEXP_SUBSTR SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
With T as
( 
select 'Cytomegalovirus Nucleoside Analog DNA Polymerase Inhibitor [EPC],DNA Polymerase Inhibitors [MoA],Nucleoside Analog [Chemical/Ingredient],Nucleoside Analog Antiviral [EPC]' CLASS 
FROM DUAL )
```

Need to pull strings with [EPC].

Desired Output:

```
Cytomegalovirus Nucleoside Analog DNA Polymerase Inhibitor [EPC], Nucleoside Analog Antiviral [EPC]
```

Comment: Do it client-side, or write a CLR function (lots of examples online on how to do regex matching with those). Doing this in pure T-SQL is possible, but an exercise in suffering. (Unless you have SQL Server 2017, then `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` can do it quite easily.)

Comment: can you please provide T-SQL code using my example?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need true regexes, since your split string is a literal. On SQL Server 2017, this should work (not tested):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ',')
FROM STRING_SPLIT('Cytomegalovirus Nucleoside Analog DNA Polymerase Inhibitor [EPC],DNA Polymerase Inhibitors [MoA],Nucleoside Analog [Chemical/Ingredient],Nucleoside Analog Antiviral [EPC]', ',')
WHERE [value] LIKE '%\[EPC\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

On SQL Server 2016, we lack `STRING_AGG`, but we do have `STRING_SPLIT`, so this will work (tested):

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + [value]
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('Cytomegalovirus Nucleoside Analog DNA Polymerase Inhibitor [EPC],DNA Polymerase Inhibitors [MoA],Nucleoside Analog [Chemical/Ingredient],Nucleoside Analog Antiviral [EPC]', ',')
    WHERE [value] LIKE '%\[EPC\]%' ESCAPE '\'
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

On earlier versions, lack of decently performing native string splitting makes this a giant pain in the behind. Many questions deal with that, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/697519/4137916). Using any of those solutions in combination with the `FOR XML PATH` trick for concatenation will work.

Alternatively, a CLR function can do this cleaner and faster (and with true regexes), but implementing those is more involved. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2515259/4137916) is a good start for that.

Last but certainly not least: if you have to perform these sorts of operations in SQL, this is usually a sign that your database design is lacking. In particular, the comma-separated values should have been separate rows with an `EPC BIT NOT NULL` column (or more generally, a `CategoryID INT REFERENCES Categories(ID)` column), and you should consider ways to have your client code store data in a way that is amenable to efficient manipulation by your database. Normalization is the keyword here.